# Aligning instrument name followed by vertical I and II

Tags: lilypond

I am trying to specify *instrumentName* like this:

```
       instrumentName = \markup {
          "Oboe"
          \center-column {
            \line { "I" }
            \line { "II" }
          }
        }
```

Which looks like this:
[image: instrument name]

But I want the word "Oboe" vertically centered.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the perfect solution, but it works:

```
    \markup {
      \column {
        \vspace #0.5
        "Oboe"
      }
      \center-column {
        \line { "I" }
        \line { "II" }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @OleV.V. in the comments above, the best way of handling this is using the `\vcenter` command. See example below:

```
\new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = \markup {
        \vcenter
        "Oboe"
        \center-column {
            \line { "I" }
            \line { "II" }
        }
    }
}
{
    c'4 d'4 e'4 f'4
}
```

Producing:

[image]